# How do I create a JavaFX Alert with a check box for "Do not ask again"?

Tags: javafx

I would like to use the standard JavaFX `Alert` class for a confirmation dialog that includes a check box for "Do not ask again". Is this possible, or do I have to create a custom `Dialog` from scratch?

I tried using the `DialogPane.setExpandableContent()` method, but that's not really what I want - this adds a Hide/Show button in the button bar, and the check box appears in the main body of the dialog, whereas I want the check box to appear in the button bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, with a little bit of work. You can override `DialogPane.createDetailsButton()` to return any node you want in place of the Hide/Show button. The trick is that you need to reconstruct the `Alert` after that, because you will have got rid of the standard contents created by the `Alert`. You also need to fool the `DialogPane` into thinking there is expanded content so that it shows your checkbox. Here's an example of a factory method to create an `Alert` with an opt-out check box. The text and action of the check box are customizable.

```
public static Alert createAlertWithOptOut(AlertType type, String title, String headerText, 
               String message, String optOutMessage, Consumer<Boolean> optOutAction, 
               ButtonType... buttonTypes) {
   Alert alert = new Alert(type);
   // Need to force the alert to layout in order to grab the graphic,
    // as we are replacing the dialog pane with a custom pane
    alert.getDialogPane().applyCss();
    Node graphic = alert.getDialogPane().getGraphic();
    // Create a new dialog pane that has a checkbox instead of the hide/show details button
    // Use the supplied callback for the action of the checkbox
    alert.setDialogPane(new DialogPane() {
      @Override
      protected Node createDetailsButton() {
        CheckBox optOut = new CheckBox();
        optOut.setText(optOutMessage);
        optOut.setOnAction(e -> optOutAction.accept(optOut.isSelected()));
        return optOut;
      }
    });
    alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonTypes);
    alert.getDialogPane().setContentText(message);
    // Fool the dialog into thinking there is some expandable content
    // a Group won't take up any space if it has no children
    alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(new Group());
    alert.getDialogPane().setExpanded(true);
    // Reset the dialog graphic using the default style
    alert.getDialogPane().setGraphic(graphic);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(headerText);
    return alert;
}
```

And here is an example of the factory method being used, where `prefs` is some preference store that saves the user's choice

```
    Alert alert = createAlertWithOptOut(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Exit", null, 
                  "Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Do not ask again", 
                  param -> prefs.put(KEY_AUTO_EXIT, param ? "Always" : "Never"), ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    if (alert.showAndWait().filter(t -> t == ButtonType.YES).isPresent()) {
       System.exit();
    }
```

And here's what the dialog looks like:

[image]

Comment: How can I check that 'Do not ask again' check box is selected or not?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `Consumer<Boolean>` instead of `Callable`

Comment: Yeah, good call MouseEvent, I have updated with Callable. Makes the lambda to process the opt out nicer.